# Not executing code issue with WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create damage with crotches in spawn time. For some reason it comes to return new WaitForSeconds(time) and doesn't go any further. There are no errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
private IEnumerator ExecuteTakeDamageForTarget(Damage damage)
{
    float time = 1000f / (1 + ((damage.ElementalDamages is null) ? 0 : damage.ElementalDamages.Length)); // 1000 ms

    SpawnViewDamage(damage.PhysicsDamage);

    if (damage.ElementalDamages != null)
    {
        for (int iterator = 0; iterator < damage.ElementalDamages.Length; iterator++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
            SpawnViewDamage(damage.ElementalDamages[iterator].DamageValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `time` has a reasonable value? .. it is also in **seconds** you seem to pass in a quite large value ...

Comment: God. Exactly!!! I forgot that it doesn't calculate in milliseconds! And in seconds! Thank you very much)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the issue here was that you provided a value in milliseconds while `WaitForSeconds` as the name already suggests expects a value in seconds.

=> Replace

```
float time = 1000f / (1 + ((damage.ElementalDamages is null) ? 0 : damage.ElementalDamages.Length));
```

by

```
 float time = 1f / (1 + ((damage.ElementalDamages is null) ? 0 : damage.ElementalDamages.Length));
```